# print average of a generated list

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I'm trying to generate a list of integers length n
n is inputted by the user.
Then print the smallest and largest number and the average of the list.

I've managed to get it to generate the numbers and print the smallest and largest number.
I've tried to divide the list by the items but I'm a bit stuck.
I think maybe my logic is off?

```
e = int(input("enter a num: "))
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(e):
    n = random.randint(1,101)
    randomlist.append(n)
    avg = randomlist/e
print("generated values:",randomlist)
print (min(randomlist),max(randomlist),avg(randomlist))
```

Comment: `avg = sum(randomlist) / e` you can't divide list by a single number you have to find the sum of the list. You can't do this `avg(randomlist)` because `avg` is variable so you can't call a variable otherwise you can use lambda `avg = lambda x: sum(x) / e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're trying to use the `/` operator on a list (in the line `avg = randomlist/e`), which is not possible. Secondly, you're then trying to *call* that average as a function (with `avg(randomlist)`). If you just need the mean of the list elements, take the sum and divide it by the number of elements.

Doing this, your code will look more like the following:

```
import random

randomlist = []
e = int(input("enter a num: "))

for i in range(e):
    n = random.randint(1,101)
    randomlist.append(n)

print("generated values:",randomlist)
print(min(randomlist),max(randomlist),sum(randomlist)/e)
```

Happy to be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the sum of the list element to find average.

```
avg = sum(randomlist)/e
```

Answer (score 1):

@deadshot is definitely right, but I would like you to show an alternative way for calculation:

To speed up your code, please use inline for loop:

```py
random_list = [random.randint(1, 101) for _ in range(e)]
```

You can also use `numpy` for taking `min`, `max` and average (`mean`)

Code:

---

```py
import random
import numpy as np

e = int(input("enter a num: "))

random_list = [random.randint(1, 101) for _ in range(e)]

print("generated values:", random_list)
print("Min: {}, Max: {}, Mean: {}\n".format(np.min(random_list), np.max(random_list), np.mean(random_list)))
```

Result:

```py
enter a num: 5
generated values: [68, 63, 79, 20, 3]
Min: 3, Max: 79, Mean: 46.6
```